# add value of columns in one row

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to add values of one row in multiple columns as a column

```
    No Name Requested Reported Finished
    1  Ali     4        4         1
    2  Amina   10       5         2

    As

    No Name Requested Reported Finished Total
    1  Ali     4        4         1       9
    2  Amina   10       5         2       17
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM` function.

### **Query**

```
SELECT no,Name,requested,reported,finished,
SUM(requested+reported+finished) AS Total
FROM tbl
GROUP BY no,Name,requested,reported,finished;
```

### **[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7fac/3)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT no,
       Name,
       requested,
       reported,
       finished,
       Isnull(requested, 0) + Isnull(reported, 0) + Isnull(finished, 0) AS Total
FROM tbl
```

Comment: While [One line answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266954/one-line-answers) are acceptable, they often land you in the Review Queue (*q.v.*). Additionally, sometimes they are not well received by the community. Its usually best to provide a brief explanation.

Comment: @jww Ok, will remember this next time.. ( I thought the projection was self-explanatory.)

Comment: The answer showed up in the review queue. I gave it the "looks good" vote because SO policy says "one-liners" are OK if they answer the question. You will know if its not well received - the answer will be downvoted.